# ActionbarSherlock update data on swipe

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I cant seem to find smooth solution for next what one would thought would be simple task:

I am using ActionbarSherlock for my application with 2 tab bars. On first tabbar i have simple input form and on second i would like to show inputed data in ListView.

Widgets and views are not problem here.. the only problem i have is next:

**I would like for my listiview to be updated when user scroll into it.**

How can I make that happen? Until now I had walk around with TextSwitcher and static variable that executed refresh of ListView.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: I did not implement it yet so far. Would like to do it right way this time. tnx